# Can't access my overridden cell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance

I'm using 3rd party framework. where I need to override a cell class. so I created a subclass. and registering the cell class in `viewDidLoad()` method. but the issue is, in super class they also registering their cell and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` method in `viewDidLoad`. So my cell class not called. 
Here I'm looking for an solution.

**Edit:**

superClass code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self reloadData];

    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BUserCell" bundle:[NSBundle chatUIBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:bUserCellIdentifier];

    [self setGroupNameHidden:YES duration:0];
}
```

superClass code where `setGroupNameHidden` has the `layoutIfNeeded()` code. and more importantly it is not a public method.

**My code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "New Conversation"
    self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "NewConversationContactCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "bUserCellIdentifier")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Like I said superclass cell class get called  if i commented out the `setGroupNameHidden:duration:` method then my cell class getting called.

Comment: please add your try and code, no one is super human!!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply ignore calling `super.viewDidLoad()`

there is another way - override the `setGroupNameHidden:duration:` method (leave it empty if necessary)

Comment: Yes i thought the same but its not a public method. so i cant override it in my class. and `super.viewDidLoad` have some more methods and i can't leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Missing Delegate calls. 
Replace

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

with

```
self.tableView.delgate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: In a super class they have done it. Why I'm using  `tableView.reloadData()` method is to check whether my cell is getting called or not.